# How to prove members of this series differ from an integer by, at most, 1/n?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

Consider the series , where a is a positive real number.

$a, 2a, 3a, .... (n-1)a$

Prove that there is one member of this series that differs from an integer by at most $\frac{1}{n}$

My approach :

Draw a modular circle of $1$, around which the number line goes infinitely often. The radius of this circle is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. All the points are now plotted onto this circle.

Let $C$ be the point on the circle which represents $ 0$,and then all the integers(which give a remainder of $0 $with division by $1$).The length of the arc $ CM $is defined as

$CM - [CM] $where $[CM] $is the floor function

I managed to reduce this to a simpler problem.

To prove that any two points,

${ja - ia \leq \frac{1}{n}}$

${(j-i)a \leq \frac{1}{n}}$

$ka \leq 1/n$

So I divided the circle into $\frac{1}{n}$ parts and thought of using the Pigeonhole Principle to solve it but there are only $(n-1)$ members of the series. I can't apply it.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Hint:  There are two winning "buckets", namely $[0,\frac 1n],[\frac {n-1}n,1]$.

Comment: @lulu You're right ! If a number is present in either of these two buckets, the problem is solved right away ! If it isn't, then n-1 numbers have to be put into n-2 buckets. By the pigeonhole principle, this means that at least two are in the same bucket and the result is proved ! Thank you so much.

Comment: But, is this an acceptable proof ? I feel like something is missing.

Comment: Sounds complete to me.  Well, you need to remark that if $ia, ja$ are in the same bucket (with $i<j$) then $(j-i)a$ is in the first, winning, bucket.

Comment: @lulu It might be in the other. (But we can fuse those two into one big winning bucket.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, thanks!

Comment: @lulu Very elegantly put, lulu